# how to make the zoom button of my own on an esri map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, esri, arcgis-js-api

i am trying to implement a zomm button (and other buttons) and using esri javascript api.

i hide esri default buttons and want to use my own for zoomin in.
see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nxuq857d/

```
    var map;
    // esri map initialization
    require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/graphic", "dojo/domReady!"], function (Map, Point,
    SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
    Graphic, Color) {
            map = new Map("map", {
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 5,
            basemap: "topo",
            slider: true // set to false to remove default zoom buttons
        });
    });
```

i want it to perform the same functionality as the default esri zoom button (zoom in). how to do that?

ALSO i am having problem with referencing the map from outside the map function... so if you can help with that as well. how to reference the map from other functions and perform for example the zoomin functionality.
after:

```
        });
    });
```

thnx a lot

Comment: please ask if you need more info... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:
http://jsfiddle.net/moizhb/rLwaytnp/

All you need is to subscribe the click event and call setZoom

```
on(dom.byId("zoomInBtn"), "click", function(evt){map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);});
on(dom.byId("zoomOutBtn"), "click", function(evt){map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);});
```

Comment: thnx. just as an aside... do you maybe know how to fix the zoom in/out custom buttons to work AS QUICKLY as the default ones? if you try your code on jsfiddle you can see they lag, you have to click, wait, click. instead of just click, click, click on the default ones. thnx a lot

Answer (score 2):

First you have to subscribe on click event of your "zoombutton" DOM element.
You can do it with native api or something like jquery ($('#zoombutton').on) or dojo/on module.

In event callback function you can access your map, because you initialized it in a global scope, and simply set next level of the map (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map.html#setlevel).

Function example:

```
document.getElementById('zoombutton').addEventListener('click', function(){
   map.setLevel(map.getLevel()+1);
});
```

If you want something more reusable and modular you can look here for more instructions https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_custom_dijit.html

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.